# Ticket Created email not sent if the partner_id and partner_id.email is connected with internal user odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-enterprise

we have a problem in odoo13. Namely, when a helpdesk ticket comes in, and the submitter enters his email and name, they will get an email that the ticket has been received. But, if an internal Odoo user logs a ticket, via the website or in the Helpdesk app, he will only get an internal note, not an email.
If you need more info I'll be glad to share. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally set that up in the user configuration:

- Go inside Settings -> Users -> go on your User
- Go to the Tab "preferences"
- Select notifications by email (and not within Odoo)

[image]